# Creating a AWS Cognito PreSignup Lambda in DotNet

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Using a .Net Core 1.0 Lambda I want to be able to create a Lambda function which handles the PreSignUp trigger from an AWS Cognito User pool.

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

public class PreSignUp_SignUp
{
  public string userPoolId { get; set; }
  public const string EmailKey = "email";
  public const string PhoneNumber = "phone_number";
  public Dictionary<string,string> userAttributes { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, string> validationData { get; set; }
}

public class PreSignup_SignUpResponse
{
  public bool autoConfirmUser { get; set; }
}

public class Function
{
  public PreSignup_SignUpResponse FunctionHandler(PreSignUp_SignUp input, ILambdaContext context)
  {
      return new PreSignup_SignUpResponse { autoConfirmUser = true };
  }
}
```

Though the request succeeds and returns a response when invoking the Lambda with an example request of:

```
{
  "datasetName": "datasetName",
  "eventType": "SyncTrigger",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "identityId": "identityId",
  "datasetRecords": {
    "SampleKey2": {
      "newValue": "newValue2",
      "oldValue": "oldValue2",
      "op": "replace"
    },
    "SampleKey1": {
      "newValue": "newValue1",
      "oldValue": "oldValue1",
      "op": "replace"
    }
  },
  "identityPoolId": "identityPoolId",
  "version": 2
}
```

When performing an actual SignUp via the .Net AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient I get back an error:

> Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model.InvalidLambdaResponseException :
>   Unrecognizable lambda output

Which I'm guessing means I have not got the shape of the response (and possibly even request) correct.

Does anyone have an example of a .Net Lambda function that works for the PreSignUp trigger in AWS Cognito?

Answer (score 17):

The cognito trigger requests/responses must contain the entire payload as specified in the Cognito trigger documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html

I have found while diagnosing this issue the best place to start is by creating a function handler that takes a JObject and then logs and return's that same object e.g.

```
public JObject FunctionHandler(JObject input, ILambdaContext context)
{
    context.Logger.LogLine("Input was: " + input);
    return input;
}
```

This captures the payload in cloudwatch logs and then helps steer you towards the strongly typed structured required.

In my case for PreSignUp I ended up creating the following types to make a simple function which auto-verifies all supplied credentials.

```
public abstract class AbstractTriggerRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("userAttributes")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> UserAttributes { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractTriggerResponse
{
}

public class TriggerCallerContext
{
    [JsonProperty("awsSdkVersion")]
    public string AwsSdkVersion { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("clientId")]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
}

public abstract class AbstractTriggerBase<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest: AbstractTriggerRequest
    where TResponse: AbstractTriggerResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public int Version { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("triggerSource")]
    public string TriggerSource { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("region")]
    public string Region { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("userPoolId")]
    public string UserPoolId { get; set; }  
    [JsonProperty("callerContext")]
    public TriggerCallerContext CallerContext { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("request")]
    public TRequest Request { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public TResponse Response { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("userName", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class PreSignUpSignUpRequest : AbstractTriggerRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("validationData")]
    public Dictionary<string,string> ValidationData { get; set; }
}
```

The Lambda function then ends up with the following signature:

```
public class Function
{
    public PreSignUp_SignUp FunctionHandler(PreSignUp_SignUp input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        context.Logger.LogLine("Auto-confirming everything!");

        input.Response = new PreSignUpSignUpResponse {
            AutoConfirmUser = true,
            // you can only auto-verify email or phone if it's present in the user attributes
            AutoVerifyEmail = input.Request.UserAttributes.ContainsKey("email"),
            AutoVerifyPhone = input.Request.UserAttributes.ContainsKey("phone_number") 
        };

        return input;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else running into issues writing Lambda triggers for Cognito.

Comment: This is a great answer but also check out DaddyCoder's response for updated syntax for .netcore 3.1 apps as there is a new JSON serializer that you will likely be using

Answer (score 7):

The previous two responses are now inaccurate unless you still use the old, less performant `Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer`. This old serializer uses `Newtonsoft.Json` while the new `Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer` implements the recent `System.Text.Json`.

As a result, a `JObject` parameter is no longer appropriate and should instead be replaced with `JsonElement`. If you try to use `JObject` with this new serializer, you will get an error since the serializer doesn't know how to deal with this object.

You should read [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/) to gain a better understanding of how it all works, but you access properties of the `JsonElement` using `GetProperty("[insert property name here]")`.

For example:

```
public async Task<JsonElement> FunctionHandler(JsonElement input, ILambdaContext context)
{
    var request = input.GetProperty("request");
    var userAttributes = request.GetProperty("userAttributes");
    string email = userAttributes.GetProperty("email").GetString();

    return input;
}
```

This way, you don't need to construct entire classes to accommodate the required request and response parameters, just get and set the properties you need.

Comment: This is correct. The JsonElement class also plays nicely with logging, so following Bittercoder's recommended starting point of logging the input you can still just use the syntax: `context.Logger.LogLine("Input was: " + input);` to see what the request payload looks like in Cloudwatch logs.

Answer (score 4):

There is already another great answer in here. However I'm not a expert .NET developer so this solution makes more sense to me.

```
class AutoVerifyEmail
{
    public AutoVerifyEmail() { }

    public JObject AutoVerifyEmailPreSignup(JObject input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        //Console.Write(input); //Print Input

        input["response"]["autoVerifyEmail"] = true;
        input["response"]["autoConfirmUser"] = true;

        return input;
    }
}
```